# Spring RestTemplate gives different response from all other browsers, even wget etc

Tags: spring, rss, wget, resttemplate, google-news

Using two different web browsers (with cookies etc... cleared) and wget, and I get the correct response from a google-news rss url `https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/q/QUERY/My%20Search?ned=us&hl=en`.

However, I tried pretending to be wget through Spring's RestTemplate via

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "*/*");
headers.set("Accept-encoding", "identity");
headers.set("User-Agent","Wget/1.19.1 (cygwin)");

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/q/QUERY/My%20Search?ned=us&hl=en",
    HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers), String.class
);
System.out.println(responseEntity.getBody);
```

the result is correct from a syntax point of view except there are no item's, i.e. no news articles.

I tested with `http://httpbin.org/headers`, so I know I'm sending out the EXACT same headers as wget (which DOES work).

httpbin.org output using wget

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Wget/1.19.1 (cygwin)"
  }
}
```

httpbin.org output using RestTemplate configured using above code:

```
{
 "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Wget/1.19.1 (cygwin)"
  }
}
```

Exactly the same headers yet completely different results.
Anyone have any idea what aspects of tcp or http google is using to censor their output to Spring based programs?

Comment: Are you sending both requests from the same machine?

Comment: @msparer yes exactly the same machine.  over similar time frames, wget first, then spring first, sometimes firefox first, etc.

Comment: @msparer And no ipv6 temporary address, only a single link-local address, and of course a single ipv4 address assigned by my isp.

Answer (score 2):

The issue may have been resolved long time back, nobody put any answer here.

I had the same issue and it turned out to be implicit encoding by `RestTemplate(String url, ...)` API.  If the URL is already encoded, pass it in as URI `RestTemplate(URI uri, ...)`. Otherwise, pass it in as string. That resolved my issue.